# can't run windows update, error 0x8024800c

Tags: windows-7, updates

I've just installed windows 7 home premium 64bit on my Asus K55vd laptop. The error 0x8024800c. I can't seem to perform any of the windows updates. I'm able to connect to the Internet without issues. Anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have Intel Rapid Storage Technologies software installed on your computer?  If so, those drivers could have gotten corrupted. I just ran into this issue today, and installing a newer version of this software (I went from 11.1 to 11.7, but they've got much newer versions than that) resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

the code 0x8024800c means a timeout issue.

```
//
// MessageId: WU_E_DS_LOCKTIMEOUTEXPIRED
//
// MessageText:
//
// The data store section could not be locked within the allotted time.
//
#define WU_E_DS_LOCKTIMEOUTEXPIRED       _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x8024800CL)
```

The datastore is located in `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` and [Microsoft recommends it to exclude the folder from your anti virus tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939908%28WS.10%29.aspx#av).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have antivirus software installed yet. I'm still kinda stumped on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you use Microsoft Security Essentials? This is also a Av tool.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and following worked for me.

1) Open **CMD** as "run as administrator":

[image]

2) once the scan completes, restart windows updates and rerun windows updates(also make sure your Windows license shows "windows is activated") :

[image]