# Cannot install update KB3033929 even with Windows SP1

Tags: windows-update

I have the same issue mentioned in this thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1129271/why-am-i-not-able-to-apply-the-update-kb3033929-on-my-windows-7-computer) but I do have Windows 7 Service Pack 1 installed:

[image]

However, I still get the error message as follows:

[image]

Edit. When I try to install other software such as Google Filestream, it explicitly names the KB3033929 update as a required patch before installing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to install other software such as Google Filestream, it explicitly names the KB3033929 update as a required patch before installing. Any suggestions?

KB3033929 was released in 2015, it was replaced by more recent updates, an upwards of 30 times.

The most recent patch is [KB4503292](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=b6022f3d-ed60-4a1e-a256-6218a5afebb2) so you should be attempting to install that instead.  However, if your being told you need the other patch, it means your missing some other required patches, that likely will prevent you from installing KB4503292.

**You should use Windows Update to install any missing updates released in the last 4 years.**

> Where can I see a chronological list of Microsoft's patches which have been released?

Microsoft has posted a list of every update since 2016 on the [Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009469/windows-7-sp1-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-update-history) page.

> I just tried to install the patch KB4503292 but I get the error message "Installer encountered an error 0x8024800c.

You either have required Windows Update services disabled or you have system files that are corrupted.  Since there isn’t enough details, [can't run windows update, error 0x8024800c](https://superuser.com/questions/1104165/cant-run-windows-update-error-0x8024800c), should provide the solution to that problem.

Whatever is causing that problem is different than the question you asked about and will not be answered in this particular answer.

**”The update is not applicable to your computer”only appears for two reasons.**  You downloaded the wrong version of the patch (IA, x86, x64) or you had one of the patches that superseded the patch in question that was released since 2015.  The fact you didn’t get this error when you attempted to install KB4503292 indicates it was the correct patch and you now have a different problem.